# Create a container like std::integral_constant

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, constexpr

I would like to create a "container-version" of `std::integral_constant`. That is a type parametrized with an element-type and non-type parameters:

```
enum class A {
    a = 1 << 0, 
    b = 1 << 1, 
    c = 1 << 2
};

template<typename T, T... Values>
struct static_container final {};

template<typename T, T... Ts>
constexpr auto make_static_container(T...) { // wrong
    return static_container<T, Ts...>{};
}

template<typename F, F... FF>
void inline set(static_container<F, FF...>) {
    std::cout << sizeof... (FF) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    constexpr static_container<A, A::a, A::b> sc1{}; //ok
    constexpr auto sc2 = make_static_container(A::a, A::c); // not-ok

    set(sc1);    
    set(sc2);    
}
```

Above you can see that I can create `sc1` with explict type.

Now I like to have a helper function to create such a type without specifying the (redundant) enum-type.

The output here is:

```
2
0
```

Any hints?

Comment: What is the error you are getting and with what compiler?

Comment: Compiles on VS2015

Comment: [Compiles with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/604bd7401ede4373)

Comment: [Compiles with gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d27a529a01534076)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear here: there is no compilation error, but the "container" is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a followup to your comment regarding `std::integral_constant`, here's what that would look like:

```
template<typename T, T... Values>
constexpr auto make_static_container(std::integral_constant<T, Values>...) noexcept {
    return static_container<T, Values...>{};
}
```

The callsite will have to change since the function is now taking `std::integral_constant<T>`s rather than `T`s directly; it is a bit noisier, but variable templates keep it from being *too* painful:

```
template<A a>
using A_ = std::integral_constant<A, a>;

template<A a>
constexpr A_<a> a_{};

int main() {
    // explicit construction via alias template:
    constexpr auto sc1 = make_static_container(A_<A::a>{}, A_<A::b>{});
    // implicit construction via variable template:
    constexpr auto sc2 = make_static_container(a_<A::a>, a_<A::c>);

    set(sc1);
    set(sc2);
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a0c61b42501ecf0)**</kbd>

(As an aside, the separate definition of `static_container::value` in the demo [becomes unnecessary in C++17](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/f8sQCU5iraZcdJvk).)

Comment: Interesting idea with template variables.

Comment: @wimalopaan : Until recently I had no opinion of or use for them, but using [Boost.Hana](http://www.boost.org/libs/hana/) lately has given me new perspective. :-]

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you don't pass the arguments of the function to the list of template arguments for the returned value creation

```
template<typename T, T... Ts>
constexpr auto make_static_container(T... /* !!! unused values !!! */) { // wrong
    return static_container<T, Ts...>{};
}
```

So the only deduced template is `T`; no template not-type values `Ts` are deduced; so the type returned is

```
return static_container<T>{};
```

that is with zero values.

You should be able to use the arguments of the function and pass they as template not type paramenters; something like

```
template<typename T0, typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto make_static_container (T0 const t0, Ts const ... ts)
 { return static_container<T0, t0, ts...>{}; }
```

but this is impossible (as far I know) in C++11/C++14 because the `t0`/`ts` values aren't `constexpr` values

Comment: Yes, thats indeed impossible, since a constexpr function must also be callable in a non-constexpr context.

Comment: I wonder if there could be a solution using std::integral_constant<> as a template template parameter of make_static_container together with a explicit instantiation of make_static_container instead of a parameter list.... But I can't get it right.